# How to Force WinRT App to be Fullscreen on Windows 10?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

WinRT App runs fullscreen on Windows 8.1, but on Windows 10 it runs windowed and could be scaled as desired. How can I block this feature and force the app for fullscreen?

Comment: It's a very good question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to force the app to load in fullscreen mode during the "Page_Loaded" event, check this:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
    }
```

If you want to try to change to full screen during runtime you could try this code:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();          
    }
```

to use ApplicationView methods you may have to add a reference:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
```

Comment: It's that easy.